# hibernate converting char to binary

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My JPA entity has a UUID attribute, which is stored as char(36) in mysql. When I query data i'm receving `66323735-3039-6262-2d31-3764392d3466` instead of `f27509bb-17d9-4f37-b336-8603f2d34394`. When I enabled hibernate logs, I could see

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_1_0_] : [BINARY]) - [66323735-3039-6262-2d31-3764392d3466]
```

extracted value is `[BINARY]` instead of `[VARCHAR]` like other attributes.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Also,

1. I've tried to run hibernate generated query on mysql and that returns correct results.
2. Other column values including UUIDs are being returned correctly.
3. I'm using an interface based entity projection to retrieve limited data and not the whole entity.

edit: I just added `trim(colName)` and now it's returning correct UUID value. But still not sure of the issue at hand.

Comment: please add your entity class of that table

Answer (score 0):

Do this for hibernate 6. It will generate character type (for mysql char(36)).

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
protected UUID id;
```